# elisp function help (learning elisp): popup list of servers, prompt for user input, then execute function to connect

Tags: shell, emacs

Caveat: 
I am a NOOB in the elisp world. I am looking for advice where to start to look for directed self education materials with the below query. I am open to: "this seems to be the silliest/hardest/overly complicated/non-lispy way of doing this why not try x". Thank you for all of the help.

Query:
I would like to implement something similar to a shell script I use but in elisp. I can share the shell script if that makes my question clearer. I am using emacs to connect to remote servers using plink on windows. I have a number of functions like so e.g.:

```
(defun server ()
  (setq explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash")
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory "/plink:un@ip:~/"))
    (shell)))
```

I would like to combine all of these into an Emacs command `connect`. I would like to call `M-x connect`, have a popup list of possible connections, enter the connection number into the minibuffer, and then execute the appropriate function based on the minibuffer input.

Comment: `interactive` needs to come first in a defun, immediately after the doc string (if there is one).

Answer (score 0):

Use `completing-read` to select from a number of options, with completion.  This is how I would start at solving your actual problem:

```
(defvar jpk/connect-list '("foo" "bar" "127.0.0.1"))
(defun jpk/connect (host)
  (interactive (list (completing-read "Server: " jpk/connect-list nil t)))
  (let* ((explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash")
         (user "un")
         (method "plink")
         (default-directory (format "/%s:%s@%s:~/"
                                    method user host)))
    (shell (format "*shell:%s@%s*" user host))))
```

(Aside: `find-file` + tramp already does completion on hosts defined in `~/.ssh/config`.  I don't know how well that works on Windows, though.)

If you still want to go down the multiple functions route, first realize that you have completion in `M-x`, and maybe that's sufficient.  If not, `completing-read` returns strings, and the way to turn strings into symbols is `intern`.  Then use `call-interactively` to call the function.

```
(defun connect-foo ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Connecting to foo..."))

(let ((host "foo")) ;; this could be from `completing-read` as above
  (call-interactively (intern (format "connect-%s" host)))) ;; run connect-foo
```